# Unable to perform file IO in java

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I am a begineer at java and wrote the below problem for postfix evaluataion. Although the program works fine for the console IO. It has problems when using files. I am trying to get the answers of the program in a file `output00.txt`, but the file is empty. 
Here is the code. I have left out methods which are irrevanlant to this issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {


     FileReader input = new FileReader("input00.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(input)   ;
        FileWriter output = new FileWriter("output00.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(output);
        while (true)  {
          String lineReader = in.readLine();
          if (lineReader==null) {
              break;
          }
          Stack<String> m_Stack = new Stack<String>();

          m_Stack.addAll(Arrays.asList(lineReader.trim().split("[ \t]+")));

          if (m_Stack.peek().equals("")){
              continue;
          }
          try  {
            double finVal = evaluateRPN(m_Stack);
            if (!m_Stack.empty()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            out.write(finVal + "\n");
          }
          catch (Exception e)  {System.out.println("error");}
        }
      }
```

File input00.txt contains

```
8 9 +
7 6 -
7 7 * 9 -
```

Comment: are you looking for the output file at the right place ? try deleting and see if it gets recreated. the code looks fine, except that you dont close the output stream. btw is this a homework ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `out.flush()` to flush what you've written to the file, or call `out.close()` which should automatically flush whatever's been buffered. Actually, you should call `close()` anyways because it's good practice, if there's some way for you to exit the while() loop.

Comment: Good answer but a bit too relaxed when it comes to closing the stream. You must call `close()` anyways - not should. Because it is the only valid way.

Comment: There's a catch block inside the loop that doesn't seem to do anything but output the error then allow the loop to run round again.  You should wrap the loop with the catch and add a "finally" with the out.close() method to ensure you clean up.

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the stream. Try `out.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by adding `out.flush()`  after the write statement. It would then write the buffer to the file.